# Encoding issue when trying to scrape a page

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using beautifulSoup to scrape a page that has a ISO-8859-1 encoding however I've run into my little hiccup.

I have a line that reads:

```
logging.info("Processing [%s]" % (link))
```

The variable `link` is one of the values scraped from beautifulsoup. It is a Unicode string and I can print it by typing `print link`. It shows up on the console exactly the way it was scraped but the line above throws this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've read up on Unicode right now but I can't figure out why it is able to print it but it can't log it.

The string in question is this:

```
booba-concert-à-bercy
```

Any ideas on where I'm mucking this up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding a file called `sitecustomize.py` in my `Python/Lib/site-packages` directory. This file contained two lines: `import sys` and `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`.

The default encoding prior to that was `ascii` and therefore the issues. Now I don't need to specify an explicit encoding for the link variable as it uses the default encoding i.e. `utf-8` and converts it to that.

Of course, I'll never see the characters properly until my terminal in the same encoding but that won't break my code.

Answer (score 3):

`logging` doesn't like `unicode`; pass it bytes.

```
logging.info("Processing [%s]" % (link.encode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Hi Ignacio. That didn't work for me. I still get the same error. Is there some other settings about my environment that could cause this. Thanks.

Comment: If I encode the string to `cp850` which seems to be Windows terminal encoding, it works fine but I'm wondering why that even though I specified the encoding from your example to be `utf-8` it still tried to encode it to ASCII.

Comment: I managed to solve this by addin a file called `sitecustomize.py` in my `Python/Lib/site-packages` directory. This file contained two lines: `import sys` and `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`. The default encoding prior to that was `ascii` and therefore the issues. Now I don't need to speicify an explicit encoding for the `link` variable as it uses the default encoding i.e. `utf-8` and converts it to that. Is this a good solution to the issue? Of course, I'll never see the characters properly until my terminal in the same encoding but that won't break my code.